# Joomla Profile Custom Field Placement

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

I just successfully added a custom field "Address" in the User Profiles using this [tutorial](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin).

However, in the picture below, the custom field is in a separate `<div>` from the core fields. Is there any way I could have the "Address" field right below the "Confirm email Address"?

Given that the tutorial never included any HTML files for layout.

[image: The "misplaced" Address field.]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [Joomla's Override facility](http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla), that is the standard way for customizing any component views HTML according to our requirement.

In JED already some extensions available to add [custom registration fields](http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=custom%20registration%20form) you can check that too.

Hope its helps..

Answer (score 0):

Joomla provides user profile plugin using which we can do this. we have to change it's name and Label using override and changing plugin's xml file.